# gRPC wait server ready

Tags: grpc, grpc-c#, grpc-c++

I'm writing test (with gtest) with grpc similar to the following (in C++ pseudocode):

```
class Fixture {
  void SetUp() { m_server = BuildAndStart(); }
  void TearDown() { m_server->Shutdown(); }
};

TEST_F(Fixture, Test1) { ASSERT_EQ(clientStub->rpcCall(ctx), grpc::Status::OK); }
TEST_F(Fixture, Test2) { ASSERT_EQ(clientStub->rpcCall(ctx), grpc::Status::OK); }
```

When compiling (clang++11) with a thread sanitizer (grpc library compiling with tsan too) sometimes I get an error **UNAVALABLE** (code 14) with logs: "Failed to pick subchannel", "Failed to connect to all addresses" and observe the state of the channel is **TRANSIENT_FAILURE**.

But only the first test always fails (Test1). Searching the internet I found the following [suitable solution](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/grpc/grpc/+/HEAD/examples/python/wait_for_ready/)

In other words, with tsan I guess grpc library does not have enough time to fully initialize (Test2 is always OK). After use `grpc::ClientContext::set_wait_for_ready(bool)` method problem solved

```
TEST_F(Fixture, Test1) { ASSERT_EQ(clientStub->rpcCall(ctxWithWait), grpc::Status::OK); }
TEST_F(Fixture, Test2) { ASSERT_EQ(clientStub->rpcCall(ctxWithWait), grpc::Status::OK); }
```

My questions are:

1. `grpc::ClientContext::set_wait_for_ready(bool)` marked as EXPERIMENTAL (C++ api) and may be removed in the future, but `grpc::ClientContext::set_fail_fast(bool)` method is **DEPRECATED**. It's recommended to use `wait_for_ready()`. Is it true that in the future `set_wait_for_ready` should become a replacement `set_fail_fast`?
2. Are there any other ways to solve this problem? I was also looking at [ChannelState API](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/grpc/grpc/+/refs/heads/chromium-deps/2016-09-09/doc/connectivity-semantics-and-api.md) method `bool grpc::ChannelInterface::WaitForConnected(T deadline)`. Which way is more correct and reliable?

I will also need to implement similar logic in C# code. In C# this is a `CallOptions.WithWaitForReady(bool)` method, but it's **EXPERIMENTAL** too

Wished to clear up a misunderstanding and choose the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `grpc::ClientContext::set_wait_for_ready(bool)` became a regular API so you don't worry about `EXPERIMENTAL` mark anymore.
2. Using `WaitForConnected` also works. Both can be the right solution for this case because it's in the unit test and it's unlikely to see the server restart during the test.